# Keep only the text of a label

Tags: r, quanteda

In a text which have formating labels such as

```
data.frame(id = c(1, 2), text = c("something here <h1>my text</h1> also <h1>Keep it</h1>", "<h1>title</h1> another here"))
```

How can someone keep with a comma separate option only the text exist inside in `<h1> </h1>`:

```
data.frame(text = c("my text, Keep it", "title"), id = c(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract_all`.  Using regex lookaround, get the characters after the tag, then loop over the `list` output and `paste` the extracted strings

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(text = sapply(str_extract_all(df1$text, "(?<=<h1>)[^<]+"), 
      paste, collapse=", "), id = df1$id)
#               text id
#1 my text, Keep it  1
#2            title  2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the web scraping skill.

```
library(rvest)

sapply(df$text, function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(css = "h1") %>% html_text %>% toString
}, USE.NAMES = F)

# [1] "my text, Keep it"
# [2] "title"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **quanteda** for this, you can process convert this to a corpus, and then process it via two `corpus_segment()` calls, one to get the text before , and the second to then just select the text after .  Then you can re-group the text using `texts(x, groups = docid())`, specifying the `spacer = ", "`.

Here's how, with your desired output:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.1

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2),
  text = c("something here <h1>my text</h1> also <h1>Keep it</h1>", "<h1>title</h1> another here")
)

charvec <- corpus(df, docid_field = "id") %>%
  corpus_segment("</h1>", pattern_position = "after") %>%
  corpus_segment("<h1>", pattern_position = "before") %>%
  texts(groups = docid(.), spacer = ", ")
```

Then to convert this into the `data.frame` that you want:

```r
data.frame(text = charvec, id = names(charvec))
##               text id
## 1 my text, Keep it  1
## 2            title  2
```